# Stories about Dragons Anthology Book - remember one story in particular

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dragons, anthology-book

I am trying to find the name of an anthology/story collection about dragons and or other monsters. I don't quite remember the cover but I know the first story about a dragon. The condensed version of the story is that:

- The father is a prince and is traveling and super thirsty and finds a well in like a really nice estate, he is about to drink from it but there is a dragon that owns the land that the well is on and asks for the prince's first-born daughter as payment for the water
- years later the prince becomes the king of his land and eventually has a daughter, who he raises like a prince (she's taught archery, swordfighting, etc). The princess takes off her hat because it's like summer season and her braids fall out, signaling that she's actually a princess and not a prince. So the dragon from earlier swoops in and kidnaps her.
- In the evenings where she is captive, she has to beat the prince that owns the estate in three games. the first night is chess (The prince cheated by moving a piece while the princess was yawning, but she caught it and eventually won the chess game), and the second night is archery or something like that. I don't quite remember the challenge on the third night but eventually it turns out that the prince had been turned into a dragon because he was arrogant. A very "Beauty and the Beast" kind of story.

I think this was the first story in the anthology, but I don't remember if the other stories specifically focused on dragons on if there were other creatures. I have definitely fallen down a rabbit hole trying to find this anthology, any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: Thank you so much! I read this maybe when I was 9 or 10 (around 2005 I think), I remember the cover art was maybe gray and red?